# Double integral on a compact subset

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Calculate:
$$\int \int _D \left(6x+2y^2 \right) dxdy$$
where D is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ enclosed by a parabola $y=x^2$ and a line $x+y=2$.
How to find that, how to find the limits of integration in this case? I think then i will manage to calculate the whole integral.

I think the area is the following (enclosed by points ABC):
[image]

Comment: The area bounded by $x$-axis or by $y$-axis ?

Comment: Can you draw the figure ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First $x^2 + x - 2 = 0 \iff x = 1$ or $x = -2$. Then $$\iint_D (6x^2+ 2y^2) dA =\int_{-2}^1\int_{x^2}^{2-x} (6x  +2y^2)dydx$$

Comment: but how did you find the boundaries of the second integral?

Comment: From the given functions $y = 2 - x$ and $y = x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The curves intersect at the points $(-2,4)$ and $(1,1)$. The region is bounded above by the line and below by the parabola, so you could iterate the double integral as
$$ \iint_D  = \int_{-2}^1 \int_{x^2}^{2-x}$$